# Codeigniter data not match error pop up message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was trying to do a error popup message but after I do alot of research from google, all the tutorials doesn't work to me. In this project, I search using 'rn' and post 'RN, NAME, D.O.B, AGE, GENDER, RACE, RELIGION'. Now I want to set validation for 'rn'. For example : if 'rn' doesn't match as data in database, error message will appear. (Sorry for my broken english since english is not my mother language). 
This is controller :

```
<?php

class Patient extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->model('Patient_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['content'] = 'patient/search_form';
        $data['title']="SEARCH";
        $data['sub']='SEARCH PATIENT';
        $this->load->view("design/index",$data);

    }

    public function execute_search()
    {

        $search_term = $this->input->post('search'); 

        $data['results'] = $this->Patient_model->get_results($search_term);

        $this->load->view('patient/search_results',$data);

    }


}
```

This is model :

```
<?php

class Patient_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_results($search_term='default')
    {
        // Use the Active Record class for safer queries.
        // $this->load->helper('share_function');
        $this->db->select('lifeline.pesakit.rn,lifeline.pesakit.nama,lifeline.pesakit.tarikhlahir,lifeline.jantina.nama as jantina,lifeline.agama.nama as agama,lifeline.bangsa.nama as bangsa');
        $this->db->from('lifeline.pesakit as pesakit');
        $this->db->join('lifeline.jantina','lifeline.jantina.kod = lifeline.pesakit.jantina');
         $this->db->join('lifeline.agama','lifeline.agama.kod = lifeline.pesakit.agama');
          $this->db->join('lifeline.bangsa','lifeline.bangsa.kod = lifeline.pesakit.bangsa');
        $this->db->where('rn',alphaToNumber($search_term));

        $query = $this->db->get('');

        // Return the results.
        return $query->result_array();
    }



}
```

This is view for search_form.php :

```
    <?php $this->load->view('template/header');?>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-body">
    <?php
        echo form_open('index.php/patient/execute_search');

        echo form_input(array('name'=>'search'));

        echo form_submit('search_submit','Submit');


    ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $this->load->view(

'template/footer');?>
```

This is view for search_results.php :

```
<?php $this->load->view('template/header');?>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">Patient Demographic</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <?php
            $no=0;
            foreach ($results as $row):
            $no++;
            ?>
            <table align="center" length="200" border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='6' style="font-family:arial;">

            <tr align='left' >
                <th>RN</th> <th> :</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo numberToAlpha($row['rn']);?></th>
                <th>Name</th> <th>:</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $row['nama'];?></th>
                <th>Date.of.Birth</th> <th>:</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo dateFormat($row['tarikhlahir']);?></th>
                <th></th><th></th><th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr align='left'>
                <th>Age </th><th> :</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo calculateCurrentAge ($row['tarikhlahir']);?></th>
                <th>Gender</th> <th>:</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $row['jantina'];?></th>
                <th>Race</th> <th>:</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $row['bangsa'];?></th>
                <th>Religion</th> <th> :</th> <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $row['agama'];?></th>
            </tr>

            <?php endforeach ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('template/footer');?>
```

Please help me everyone because I'm totally new for codeigniter and all I learned is from mr.google, nobody around me can help. Thank you.

Comment: `rn` is your column in table ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically if no results are found your `get_results()` function returns an empty array and the foreach loop will 'fail'. Thus you have to check if `count($results) > 0` meaning you have to check if you have any results:

```
<?php $this->load->view('template/header');?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Patient Demographic</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php
                if (count($results) > 0):
                $no = 0;
                foreach ($results as $row):
                $no++;
                ?>
                <table align="center" length="200" border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='6' style="font-family:arial;">

                    <tr align='left'>
                        <th>RN</th>
                        <th> :</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo numberToAlpha($row['rn']);?>
                        </th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>:</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo $row['nama'];?>
                        </th>
                        <th>Date.of.Birth</th>
                        <th>:</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo dateFormat($row['tarikhlahir']);?>
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr align='left'>
                        <th>Age </th>
                        <th> :</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo calculateCurrentAge ($row['tarikhlahir']);?>
                        </th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>:</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo $row['jantina'];?>
                        </th>
                        <th>Race</th>
                        <th>:</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo $row['bangsa'];?>
                        </th>
                        <th>Religion</th>
                        <th> :</th>
                        <th style="font-weight: normal;">
                            <?php echo $row['agama'];?>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php
                endforeach;
                else:
                ?>
                <p>No results found</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $this->load->view('template/footer');?>
```

Note: I moved the `</table>` bracket within the foreach loop or you are not terminating the table. I'm not sure why you want to create a new table for every `patient` but who am I to judge ;). Also there is no need to start a counter (`$no`) if you aren't going to use it.

Comment: What should I do if I want that 'No results found' message become a popup message?

Comment: Than you will have to use AJAX and jquery and everything gets a bit more complex for you (and outside the scope of your question). If you truly want to do that I would suggest researching it, and if you can't figure it out posting on stack with the tags `ajax` and `jquery`.